# AbstractDataType - Nat

Tags: abstract-data-type

I got this abstract model here and try to understand how it works but can't figure it out.

```
type: NAT
```

**constructor**

```
null: → NAT 
succ: NAT → NAT
```

**operator**

```
add: NAT×NAT→ NAT
```

**axiom**  x,y : NAT

```
add(X, null) = X
add(X, succ(Y)) = succ(add(X, Y))
```

The problem is with the add. I tried to put some numbers in but ... how does it work? -

add(2, succ(3)) = succ(add(2, 3)) ... and now? I just want 2+3 = 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAT is the set of natural numbers together with '+' and succ is the [successor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_function) (often seen in relation with the Peano axioms)

Your example for 2+3 calculates like this:

```
add(2,3) = succ(add(2,2))
         = succ(succ(add(2,1))) 
         = succ(succ(succ(add(2,0))))
         = succ(succ(succ(2)))
         = succ(succ(3))
         = succ(4)
         = 5
```

Comment: so something like this (2+3) :: add(2, succ(2)) = succ(add(2, 2)) -> succ(add(2, 1)) -> succ(add(2, 0)) and that is backwards 3 > 4 > 5 is that right?

Comment: Wait, it's not the Peano Axioms for Addition, it's very similar but it isn't since add(X, succ(Y)) is not add(succ(m),n), I'll edit in a minute.

Comment: Ok, here's the right answer now. Your calculation is right, I've written it down a bit more explicit.